# DB optimization and normalization

Tags: database, optimization, query-optimization

I have several tables with geodata: `countries`, `regions`, `cities`. Also I have a table with user profiles. Is there any logic to add `country_id`, `region_id` and `city_id` to `profiles` table? If talking about normalizing - it's wrong, because `cities` table has `region_id` and `regions` table has `country_id`, but in this case we will have additional queries.

Answer (score 0):

city_id would be a foreign key in your profiles table. The other fields (country, region) would be connected automatically in queries.

```
profiles (profile_id pk, city_id fk)
cities (city_id pk, region_id fk)
regions (region_id pk, country_id fk)
countries (country_id pk)
```

Comment: Yes, but it's still 3 more queries (or joins). It can be fast enough, but what the ideal solution for such cases?

Comment: Ideally you would always know the city, so region and country would be redundant. However, will your spacial data *always* have a city? If not, then you would need to include region and country in each table.

Comment: My use case is that i need all to search all profiles in some county. So now I should get regions then cities and only then - profiles :)